# SvelteKit - can I consume a +server.ts endpoint from a store?

Tags: frontend, backend, svelte, sveltekit

In my svelte website, I want to consume an endpoint inside a store, to fetch a list of servers for me to display in html divs. I cannot seem to understand how to call the API for me to fetch the servers.

from the serverSection component
(https://github.com/maxijabase/electricservers.com.ar/blob/master/src/components/serverSection.svelte)

`src/components/serverSection.svelte`

```
<script lang="ts">
  export let bgImage: string
  export let logo: string
  export let text: string

  import { fetchServers, serversStore } from '../stores/servers'
  import Server from './server.svelte'

  fetchServers()
</script>

<!-- some html -->
```

I'm trying to fetch a list of servers from an endpoint I created in a +server.ts file
(https://github.com/maxijabase/electricservers.com.ar/blob/master/src/routes/api/%2Bserver.ts)

this is `src/stores/servers.ts`

```
import { writable, type Writable } from 'svelte/store'

export const serversStore: Writable<any> = writable()

export const fetchServers = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/api', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      accept: 'application/json',
    },
  })
  serversStore.set(response)
}
```

this is `src/routes/api/+server.ts`

```
import type { RequestHandler } from './$types'
import { Server } from '@fabricio-191/valve-server-query'
import { serverList } from 'src/servers/serversList'
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit'

export const GET: RequestHandler = async () => {
  let infoList: Server.Info[] = []
  for await (const server of serverList) {
    const sv = await Server({ ip: server.ip, port: server.port, timeout: 3000 })
    const svInfo = await sv.getInfo()
    infoList.push(svInfo)
  }
  return json(infoList)
}
```

but I'm getting

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Module.each (/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@3.55.0/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1841:31)    
    at eval (/src/components/serverSection.svelte:28:63)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@3.55.0/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1876:22)
    at eval (/src/routes/+page.svelte:20:120)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@3.55.0/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1876:22)
    at Object.default (root.svelte:41:38)
    at eval (/src/routes/+layout.svelte:11:41)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@3.55.0/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1876:22)
    at root.svelte:40:37
    at $$render (/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@3.55.0/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1876:22)
C:\Users\Maxi\Documents\Programming\electricservers.com.ar\node_modules\.pnpm\undici@5.14.0\node_modules\undici\index.js:105
      Error.captureStackTrace(err, this)
            ^

TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api
    at fetch (C:\Users\Maxi\Documents\Programming\electricservers.com.ar\node_modules\.pnpm\undici@5.14.0\node_modules\undici\index.js:105:13)
    at async Module.fetchServers (/src/stores/servers.ts:8:20) {
  [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
      at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:553:9)
      at new URL (node:internal/url:629:5)
      at new Request (C:\Users\Maxi\Documents\Programming\electricservers.com.ar\node_modules\.pnpm\undici@5.14.0\node_modules\undici\lib\fetch\request.js:78:21)
      at fetch (C:\Users\Maxi\Documents\Programming\electricservers.com.ar\node_modules\.pnpm\undici@5.14.0\node_modules\undici\lib\fetch\index.js:136:21)
      at fetch (C:\Users\Maxi\Documents\Programming\electricservers.com.ar\node_modules\.pnpm\undici@5.14.0\node_modules\undici\index.js:103:20)
      at Module.fetchServers (/src/stores/servers.ts:8:26)
      at eval (/src/components/serverSection.svelte:19:24)
      at Object.$$render (/node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@3.55.0/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1878:22)
      at eval (/src/routes/+page.svelte:20:120) {
    input: '/api',
    code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
  }
}
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I have no idea how to do this properly

Comment: Calling `fetchServers` directly in the top level of your `script` tag makes it so it is called on the server as well, which might not be what you want. You could run it only in the browser with [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-onmount): `onMount(() => { fetchServers(); });`

Comment: @Tholle thanks for the contribution, will do. Would you happen to know if what I'm trying to do with the store and endpoint makes any sense, or is there a better way? Since the problem hasn't been solved

Comment: The error in your question seems to be related to using `fetch` on the server (`undici` can't resolve the URL), so are you getting a new error with `onMount`? Fetching the data in the browser and populating a global store might be a good solution, depending on the use case. Another approach worth exploring is [putting the data loading in a `layout`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#layout-data) so that it will be server rendered and available to child pages instead.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on using +layout.server.ts file! Although it has worked properly, and it is even working as it should when I do pnpm dev, when I deploy it in Vercel (and when I do pnpm preview) some images of the website disappear completely, and some weird random timeout errors pop up in console. This whole thing is driving me crazy. Here is the source code: https://github.com/electricservers/electricservers.com.ar and here is a video demonstration of what I'm talking about https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1056959017114664990/1056959122123259934/Code_BiyJM8XlFy.mp4